# Image size (responsive slider)

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, responsive-design

I am using the responsive http://bxslider.com/ on my Website. The Problem is, that I have got large Images with a big file size and if I want to watch my website on a mobile device, it tooks ages to load.

The bxslider works with img-tags in html and I am looking for a way, that the browser maby decide which Images Version for example large, medium or small he will chooose.

I know, how it will work for div's in css for example with media queries, but I do not know, how it is done with images in html.

Any suggestions?

Sorry, for my english :P

Answer (score 0):

For the responsive images we have to put ***max-width:100%*** to image tag. and the outer div or which element can set width. It can be re-wright repective of device width using css media query.

Comment: I am using a tool called bxslider and the Images are resizing automaticly, but I guess, this tool always use the largest file size.

Comment: If you using bxslider it is already responsive. No need to add custom styles. If it is not working you can add style max-width: 100% to img element

Comment: or you can check in your script whether it is true or false. and make it  true "responsive: true"

Answer (score 0):

Use the image you want to show for mobile users in the `src` attribute of your image and set the image with better resolution in another attribute (e.g. `data-fullsize="fullsize.jpg"`).

If the user uses a desktop PC (e.g. document width above 600 pixels), then replace the image source through the source given in the attribute `data-fullsize`.
For this, you may use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.
You could add another attribute to temporarily backup the path for the image for mobile users for responsiveness (if you change document width without reloading the page to a smaller size).